# Draft.js - convert current block to Atomic Block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs, draft-js-plugins

I'm working on a custom draft.js plugin that inserts an Atomic Block with a GIF in it. I started by copying the [Draft.js Image Plugin](https://github.com/draft-js-plugins/draft-js-plugins/tree/master/draft-js-image-plugin) as it's almost identical. I've got my plugin working but there's one issue I'm not sure best how to solve.

[image: Gif showing draft.js interaction bug]

To insert a GIF I'm following the example [addImage Modifier](https://github.com/draft-js-plugins/draft-js-plugins/blob/master/draft-js-image-plugin/src/modifiers/addImage.js#L3) in the Image Plugin. However, this always creates a new Atomic Block after the current selection. If the current block is empty, I want to place the GIF there instead.

Here's what my modifier function looks like:

```
const addGiphy = (editorState, giphyId) => {
    const contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent();

    // This creates the new Giphy entity
    const contentStateWithEntity = contentState.createEntity("GIPHY", "IMMUTABLE", {
        giphyId
    });

    const entityKey = contentStateWithEntity.getLastCreatedEntityKey();

    // Work out where the selection is
    const currentSelection = editorState.getSelection();
    const currentKey = currentSelection.getStartKey();
    const currentBlock = editorState.getCurrentContent().getBlockForKey(currentKey);

    let newEditorState;

    if (currentBlock.getType() === "unstyled" && currentBlock.getText() === "") {
        // Current line is empty, we should convert to a gif atomic block
        // <INSERT MAGIC HERE>
    } else {
        // There's stuff here, lets create a new block
        newEditorState = AtomicBlockUtils.insertAtomicBlock(editorState, entityKey, " ");
    }

    return EditorState.forceSelection(
        newEditorState,
        newEditorState.getCurrentContent().getSelectionAfter()
    );
};
```

I'm not sure how to handle the condition of converting the current block to an Atomic Block. Is this Draft.js best practice? Alternatively, am I better to always insert a new block and then remove the empty block?

For clarity, this same issue also exists in the Image Plugin, it's not something I've introduced.

Answer (score 0):

you can use  https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-modifier/#setblocktype

```
const content = Modifier.setBlockType(content, editorState.getSelection(), 'atomic');
const newState = EditorState.push(editorState, content, 'change-block-type');
```